# Importing Panda gives ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`'

Tags: python, pandas

Importing pandas worked before but suddenly start to give "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`'" when running. uninstall & reinstall won't help.

Here is my call and output on Jupyter note book:

`import pandas as pd`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
1 # Importing the libraries
----> 2 import pandas as pd

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:46
43 # let init-time option registration happen
44 import pandas.core.config_init  # pyright: ignore[reportUnusedImport] # noqa: F401
---> 46 from pandas.core.api import (
47# dtype
48ArrowDtype,
49Int8Dtype,
50Int16Dtype,
51Int32Dtype,
52Int64Dtype,
53UInt8Dtype,
54UInt16Dtype,
55UInt32Dtype,
56UInt64Dtype,
57Float32Dtype,
58Float64Dtype,
59CategoricalDtype,
60PeriodDtype,
61IntervalDtype,
62DatetimeTZDtype,
63StringDtype,
64BooleanDtype,
65# missing
66NA,
67isna,
68isnull,
69notna,
70notnull,
71# indexes
72Index,
73CategoricalIndex,
74RangeIndex,
75MultiIndex,
76IntervalIndex,
77TimedeltaIndex,
78DatetimeIndex,
79PeriodIndex,
80IndexSlice,
81# tseries
82NaT,
83Period,
84period_range,
85Timedelta,
86timedelta_range,
87Timestamp,
88date_range,
89bdate_range,
90Interval,
91interval_range,
92DateOffset,
93# conversion
94to_numeric,
95to_datetime,
96to_timedelta,
97# misc
98Flags,
99Grouper,
100factorize,
101unique,
102value_counts,
103NamedAgg,
104array,
105Categorical,
106set_eng_float_format,
107Series,
108DataFrame,
109 )
111 from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import SparseDtype
113 from pandas.tseries.api import infer_freq

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py:28
16 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import (
17isna,
18isnull,
19notna,
20notnull,
21 )
23 from pandas.core.algorithms import (
24factorize,
25unique,
26value_counts,
27 )
---> 28 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
29 from pandas.core.arrays.boolean import BooleanDtype
30 from pandas.core.arrays.floating import (
31Float32Dtype,
32Float64Dtype,
33 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from pandas.core.arrays.arrow import ArrowExtensionArray
 2 from pandas.core.arrays.base import (
 3ExtensionArray,
 4ExtensionOpsMixin,
 5ExtensionScalarOpsMixin,
 6 )
 7 from pandas.core.arrays.boolean import BooleanArray

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\arrow\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from pandas.core.arrays.arrow.array import ArrowExtensionArray
 3 __all__ = ["ArrowExtensionArray"]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\arrow\array.py:48
42 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna
44 from pandas.core import (
45missing,
46roperator,
47 )
---> 48 from pandas.core.arraylike import OpsMixin
49 from pandas.core.arrays._arrow_string_mixins import ArrowStringArrayMixin
50 from pandas.core.arrays.base import (
51ExtensionArray,
52ExtensionArraySupportsAnyAll,
53 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:21
19 from pandas.core import roperator
20 from pandas.core.construction import extract_array
---> 21 from pandas.core.ops.common import unpack_zerodim_and_defer
23 REDUCTION_ALIASES = {
24"maximum": "max",
25"minimum": "min",
26"add": "sum",
27"multiply": "prod",
28 }
31 class OpsMixin:
32# -------------------------------------------------------------
33# Comparisons

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py:8
 1 """
 2 Arithmetic operations for PandasObjects
 3 
 4 This is not a public API.
 5 """
 6 from __future__ import annotations
----> 8 from pandas.core.ops.array_ops import (
 9arithmetic_op,
10comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY,
11comparison_op,
12fill_binop,
13get_array_op,
14logical_op,
15maybe_prepare_scalar_for_op,
16 )
17 from pandas.core.ops.common import (
18get_op_result_name,
19unpack_zerodim_and_defer,
20 )
21 from pandas.core.ops.docstrings import make_flex_doc

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:58
52 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import (
53isna,
54notna,
55 )
57 from pandas.core import roperator
---> 58 from pandas.core.computation import expressions
59 from pandas.core.construction import ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike
60 from pandas.core.ops import missing

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py:21
18 from pandas.util._exceptions import find_stack_level
20 from pandas.core import roperator
---> 21 from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED
23 if NUMEXPR_INSTALLED:
24import numexpr as ne

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\check.py:5
 1 from __future__ import annotations
 3 from pandas.compat._optional import import_optional_dependency
----> 5 ne = import_optional_dependency("numexpr", errors="warn")
 6 NUMEXPR_INSTALLED = ne is not None
 7 if NUMEXPR_INSTALLED:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:132, in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
127 msg = (
128f"Missing optional dependency '{install_name}'. {extra} "
129f"Use pip or conda to install {install_name}."
130 )
131 try:
--> 132module = importlib.import_module(name)
133 except ImportError:
134if errors == "raise":

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
124   break
125level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numexpr\__init__.py:45
43 ncores = detect_number_of_cores()
44 # Initialize the number of threads to be used
---> 45 nthreads = _init_num_threads()
46 # The default for VML is 1 thread (see #39)
47 # set_vml_num_threads(1)
49 from . import version

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numexpr\utils.py:156, in _init_num_threads()
154requested_threads = int(os.environ['NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS'])
155 elif 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' in os.environ:
--> 156requested_threads = int(os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'])
157 else:
158requested_threads = n_cores

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`'
```